# What happens to outstanding .NET WebClient async operations when WinForm app closes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webclient

I am trying to understand, what exactly happens to WebClient outstanding Async operations when WinForms app is closed.  I do not actually have a problem, my question is driven by desire to understand the exact flow.

The app uses the following pattern, when download requested:

```
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
                wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(my_DownloadProgressChanged);
                wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(my_DownloadFileCompleted);
```

Event handlers are methods on a Form.  One of the concerns I have is I do not want those to get invoked when form is closed already.  I could keep references to WebClient, and -= on form close, but I'd like to not do unnecessary work to avoid new problems.

Here are questions I have:

- why is it ok to Dispose WebClient before Async operations complete?
- do we have to unregister handlers on main window shutdown, and what
  happens if we don't? my observation, is that if I close form, none of
  Async callbacks are invoked, but why exactly, how exactly does it
  shutdown?

I reviewed WebClient code but I couldn't figure this stuff out.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This superuser question has answers to yours https://superuser.com/questions/375604/does-windows-take-care-of-closing-sockets-when-processes-exit

Comment: Long story short, the Garbage Collector and operating system do their best to handle zombie processes before they spiral out of control. It was possible in languages like C/C++ to fork a process, and it would never close, consuming memory long after the main application closed. That is why, it is commonplace to use "Dispose" patterns in C#, like "using" and try/finally to tell the GC & OS that you are done with the object and to remove it with force if needed. In languages like C#/Java, you are just a manager telling the bouncer to get rid of someone from your club.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f103cb35-6e15-4017-a7f3-10fe719f1a23/regarding-zombies-thread-and-process?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: You should not be using the *using* statement when you next start an asynchronous download.  That nothing goes wrong is a side-effect of WebClient being derived from Component, a .NET 1.0 design mistake that they can't fix anymore.  You need to call its CancelAsync() method in a FormClosed event handler to avoid trouble.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant it makes sense, and that's what I suspected.  For my use however, I'll go with a less intrusive change we discussed with Eric below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is it ok to Dispose WebClient before Async operations complete?

Looking at the [Reference Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs) for WebClient, it doesn't look like it actually has any specific implementation for the Dispose method. It *shouldn't* be safe to dispose any IDisposable and expect async operations to finish successfully, but in this case it might happen to work because disposing the web client doesn't do anything to abort the open connections.

As to your question about what happens when the application exits, the operating system will terminate any open connections when the process ends.

Comment: Hmm, WebClient.Dispose did not seem empty to me.  Regarding second question, however: is it possible that callback will be invoked after Form is closed?

Comment: After the form is closed: Yes. After the application is closed: No

Comment: Since those callbacks are invoked on the UI thread, I assume adding a check to see if form is closed already and return should prevent undesired interaction with UI controls, possibly disposed already?